# Is $\pi$ or $e$ algebraic over $\mathbb R$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm reading some basic introduction on fields and Galois theory.

By definition, let $F$ be an extension field of $K$ -- An element $u$ of $F$ is said to be **algebraic** over $K$ provided that $u$ is a root of some nonzero polynomial $f \in K[x]$. If $u$ is not a root of any nonzero $f \in K[x]$, $u$ is said to be **transcendental** over $K$.

Now, this book says:  $\pi$ and $e$ are algebraic over $\mathbb R$, while transcendental over $\mathbb Q$.

But is this true? How could a polynomial $f \in R[x]$ has a root as $\pi$ or $e$?

Comment: Try $f(x)=x-\pi$.

Comment: $\pi$ and $e$ are real numbers

Comment: Every element of a field $K$ is algebraic over $K$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** What about $f(x) = x - e$.

Comment: Or $f(x) = x - \pi$

Comment: @SubSevn Exactly!

Comment: (+1) Might as well kill both birds with one stone: $f(x) = (x - e)(x - \pi)$...? :)

Comment: @user86418 That's right!!